# What does "String[] args" contain in java?

Tags: java

When I run the following program:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(args);
    }
{
```

It prints: `[Ljava.lang.String;@153c375`

and when I run it again, it prints: `[Ljava.lang.String;@1d1e730`

it gives me different output each time

So, what does "`[Ljava.lang.String;@153c375`" mean?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update**: I just realized I never answered the question *"What does “String[] args” contain in java?"* :-) It's an array of the command-line arguments provided to the program, each argument being a `String` in the array.

And we now resume with our regularly-scheduled answer...

`args` is an *array*. To see individual command-line arguments, index into the array — `args[0]`, `args[1]`, etc.:

You can loop through the args like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int index;

        for (index = 0; index < args.length; ++index)
        {
            System.out.println("args[" + index + "]: " + args[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

For `java Test one two three`, that will output:

```
args[0]: one
args[1]: two
args[2]: three
```

Or loop like this if you don't need the index:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (String s : args)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

> So, what does `"[Ljava.lang.String;@153c375"` mean?

That's Java's default `toString` return value for `String[]` (an array of `String`). See [`Object#toString`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29). The `[` means "array", the `L` means "class or interface", and `java.lang.String` is self-explanatory. That part comes from [`Class#getName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29). The `;@153c375` is `;@` followed by the `hashCode` of the array as a hex string. (I think the default implementation of `hashCode` for `Object` indicates where in memory the array is located, which is why it's different for different invocations of your program, but that's unspecified behavior and wouldn't be any use to you anyway.)

Answer (score 8):

`String[] args` in main method is the String array of the [command line arguments](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).

`[Ljava.lang.String;@1d1e730` are the class name (`[Ljava.lang.String` is `String[]`) and the object's hashcode (`@1d1e730`);

if you want to print the actual values of the Strings in the array, you can use a simple for-each loop:

```
for(String arg:args)
    System.out.println(arg);
```

Answer (score 7):

It's a form of [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) used for disambiguating method overloads. The method name is appended by a series of characters describing the parameters and return type: the parameters appear sequentially inside parentheses, and the return type follows the closing parenthesis. The codes are as follows:

- Z: boolean
- B: byte
- C: char
- S: short
- I: int
- J: long
- F: float
- D: double
- L fully-qualified-class-name ; : fully qualified class
- [ type : array of type
- V: void

So according to above codes `[Ljava.lang.String;@153c375`

Array of string (java.lang.String fully qualified class name) followed by hascode.

Answer (score 4):

Default implementation of `toString` method for Object is `classname;@identityHashCode`. 
I think, this is what you expect:

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(args));
```

Answer (score 4):

`String[] args` is an Array of Strings and contains the arguments that were given when the application was started. Java does not require you to use the name args, you could just as well specify `String[] foo` but that will make things unclear if you later read your code again.

Answer (score 1):

It's a string array.

1. Modify your code to this:

```
public class Test{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       System.out.println(args[0]);
   }
}
```

2. Now compile this code:

> $>javac Test.java

3. Now run:

> $>java Test hello

This will print: "hello"

Because "hello" is the argument you are passing to your class.

If you try: `args[x], where x=0..n` and run your class via command line: java Test your arguments, then you will see any contents which you pass..

Answer (score 0):

The main method has a parameter that is an array of String references.
So each time you try to print args, it gives you memory location of array 'args' because this String array args located a place in memory for array elements.

That say you have an simple program called 'HelloWorld.java' like this:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        for(int i =0; i<args.length; i++)
            System.out.println(""+args[i]);
    }
}
```

Ready to test this program with command line interface:
[image]

```
java HelloWorld a b c
```

We can see that this program prints thouse arguments after 'java Helloworld'
a
b
c

Answer (score 0):

Lets make it simple

**1: Write a simple class named "*test*"**

```java
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Passed argument is: " + args[0]);
    }
}
```

**2: Now compile it in the following way**

```
javac test.java
```

**3: Now run this by passing an argument**

```
java test Ayoub
```

** the output will be**

```
Passed argument is: Ayoub
```